# Gdk: how to remove bit from event mask in Python?

Tags: python, gtk, bitwise-operators, gdk

I want to remove the `POINTER_MOTION_MASK` from my window's events. I tried:

```
win.set_events(win.get_events() & ~Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
```

however, I get this error:

```
TypeError: Expected a Gdk.EventMask, but got int
```

How should I remove the bit from the event mask?

Comment: I tried this out with *from gi.repository import Gdk* and had no problem.

Comment: Well, I corrected the question. The point is that `GdkWindow.set_events()` requires a `Gdk.EventMask`.

Answer (score 1):

The ~ operator changes the result type:

```
>>> type(Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
<class 'gi.repository.Gdk.GdkEventMask'>
>>> type(~Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK)
<type 'int'>
```

So you need to cast the result. I guess this should work:

```
win.set_events(win.get_events() & (Gdk.EventMask)~Gdk.EventMask.POINTER_MOTION_MASK))
```